# IMS Clearwater configuring Application Server

Tags: sip, voip, restcomm, ims

I want to configure application server (in this case Restcomm) to ims clearwater so I added IFC line to /usr/share/clearwater/ellis/web-content/js/app-servers.json. Notice REGISTER SPT method.

```
"Restcomm" : "<InitialFilterCriteria><Priority>1</Priority><TriggerPoint><ConditionTypeCNF></ConditionTypeCNF><SPT><ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated><Group>0</Group><Method>REGISTER</Method><Extension></Extension></SPT><SPT><ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated><Group>0</Group><Method>INVITE</Method><Extension></Extension></SPT></TriggerPoint><ApplicationServer><ServerName>sip:192.168.56.101:5080</ServerName><DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling></ApplicationServer></InitialFilterCriteria>"
```

I want to do scenario
[ims registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvCCc.png)
but red circled flow is not done.

User created in Ellis Gui is registering fine in IMS but in trace I don't see REGISTER request to application server. What I have to do to achieve that flow except adding IFC line? Based on above flow, should Sprout component send independently REGISTER to AS?

Settings in zoiper for Ellis user. [zoiper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozC0B.png)

[EDIT]

After testing I have some observations, i.a.:

1.When I removed INVITE SPT, and set only REGISTER SPT then flow works as I wanted and described above. So how to set few SPT?

```
"Restcomm-Register" : "<InitialFilterCriteria><Priority>1</Priority><TriggerPoint><ConditionTypeCNF></ConditionTypeCNF><SPT><ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated><Group>0</Group><Method>REGISTER</Method><Extension></Extension></SPT></TriggerPoint><ApplicationServer><ServerName>sip:192.168.56.101:5080</ServerName><DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling></ApplicationServer></InitialFilterCriteria>"
```

2.Not clear behaviour I noticed, when I created second server (with INVITE only), then provisioned two numbers via ellis gui, first number set to Restcomm-Register (above), second to Restcomm-Invite (below). On the Restcomm AS I have simple sip servlet app which is triggered on Invite and Register requests. I assumed that first number would only trigger simple app only on Register request but NOT! This number can also trigger Invite method... Why is this happennig if Register iFC only is added for first number? I thought that Invite should be send to build-in MMTel AS). On the other hand second number triggers only Invite method as I want.

```
"Restcomm-Invite" : "<InitialFilterCriteria><Priority>1</Priority><TriggerPoint><ConditionTypeCNF></ConditionTypeCNF><SPT><ConditionNegated>0</ConditionNegated><Group>0</Group><Method>INVITE</Method><Extension></Extension></SPT></TriggerPoint><ApplicationServer><ServerName>sip:192.168.56.101:5080</ServerName><DefaultHandling>0</DefaultHandling></ApplicationServer></InitialFilterCriteria>"
```

Both servers Restcomm-Register and Restcomm-Invite are the same server (the same IP) but with different SPT.